# Crytek SSAO implementation producing odd result

Tags: graphics, glsl, fragment-shader, plane, ssao

I have been trying to better match my SSAO to Crytek's original implementation. Their [Finding Next Gen - CryEngine 2](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Chapter8-Mittring-Finding_NextGen_CryEngine2.pdf) document states

> To reduce the sample count we vary the sample position for nearby
> pixels. The initial sample positions are distributed around the origin
> in a sphere and the variation is achieved by reflecting the sample
> positions on a random 3D plane through the origin

I have implemented this as the following: [Full Shader](https://pastebin.com/uDvSKVCx)

```
vec3 plane = texture(texNoise, uvCoords * noiseScale).xyz - vec3(1.0);

for(int i = 0; i < ssao.sample_amount; ++i) {

    vec3 samplePos = reflect(TBN * ssao.samples[i].xyz, plane);
    samplePos = viewSpacePositions + samplePos * radius;
    /....
 }
```

My result appears far from the original Crytek SSAO implementation with an overall odd look and occlusion seemingly only appearing on the right side.

[image]